# Java serialize tuple with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I've got the following JSON:

```
"activityContainer" : {
   "activities": [
        [
            {
                "value": "483ab684-9854-4350-a5d0-a21b7d619c05"
            },
            {
                "type": "Activity",
                "uuid": "483ab684-9854-4350-a5d0-a21b7d619c05",
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to serilize and deserialize it using Jackson, the followings are the classes createad using https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"activities"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class ActivityContainer{

  @JsonProperty("activities")
  private List<List<Activity>> activities = new ArrayList<List<Activity>>();
  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  // getters and setters
}
```

And:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"value",
"type",
"uuid"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Activity {

  @JsonProperty("value")
  private String value;
  @JsonProperty("type")
  private String type;
  @JsonProperty("uuid")
  private String uuid;
  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  // getters and setters
}
```

Whenever I try to deserialize the JSON string in the ActivityContainer class and serialize it back again the output is the one expected. But if I try to create a new Activity, fill its fields, and add it to the list of ActivityContainer the serialization output is the following:

```
"activityContainer" : {
  "activities": [
     [
        {
            "value": "483ab684-9854-4350-a5d0-a21b7d619c05",
            "type": "Activity",
            "uuid": "483ab684-9854-4350-a5d0-a21b7d619c05",
        }
     ]
  ]
}
```

NOTE: I can't modify the JSON.

Does anyone have some idea why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing it's hard to tell. I'd suspect the error is somewhere in the code you're not showing. That first json also looks like you have 2 partially defined activities, i.e. one with a value and another one with a type and uuid - and that seems to be very odd.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The property value should not be a String since it's contained in a json object of its own. Another structure, like a Map is more appropriate for it.

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion? `"483ab684-9854-4350-a5d0-a21b7d619c05"` is technically a String, isn't it? Also in the question it is clearly mentioned, that the generated code should not be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you overlooked, that ...

```json
        [
            {
                "value": "483ab684-9854-4350-a5d0-a21b7d619c05"
            },
            {
                "type": "Activity",
                "uuid": "483ab684-9854-4350-a5d0-a21b7d619c05",
            }
        ]
```

...are actually two objects, not just one. So if you want to have exactly the same structure, you have to add two `Activity` objects to the list, not just one: one with "value" set, and one with "type" and "uuid" set.

However the JSON is far from ideal with "value" and "uuid" obviously duplicated (and maybe two entries belonging to the same set of data - which I cannot say for sure with the information given). In case the structure comes from a third party it might be worth the effort to further discuss that structure.

Otherwise you might need additional code to transform the input and/or output to the model you want to really have.